# How to display a div forcefully

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js

I am using `backbone.js` views.

i have a list of expandable backbone views and inside which i have table. One of the column have `dropdown` div.

this div get partially hidden behind another view.[image]
in above picture there is a `dropdown` view hidden behind the list view.

So i just want to ask how to force the div to display, not get overlapped.
I don't want to use fixed position as it will fix the position for all the position.

to be noted : using mozilla developer tool, in 3D view i found, the div view is on the TOP MOST layer.
[image]

my html after loading in browser :

```
 <div class="dropdown open" >
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><div class="menuitem"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="res" style="opacity: 0.0; position: absolute; left: -9999px">Response</label></div></li>
    <li><div class="menuitem"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="req" style="opacity: 0.0; position: absolute; left: -9999px">Request</label></div></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

css over the dropdown div:

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML + the CSS you have.

Comment: probably an overflow:hidden; issue but without your html and css i m just guessing.

Comment: Hard to say without seen your html/css. But as Patsy issa said it can be overflow:hidden. Or maybe wrong zindex?

Comment: Koka, maybe you only need to use `bottom:0;` instead of the `top:100%;` ? Or can you replicate the problem in your code to be fixed? http://jsfiddle.net/EaWfz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with z index of parent list div. z index of this parent list div was more than the z index of `dropdown` div.

So i simply reduced the z index of `dropdown` div to less than the parent list div. and the problem is solved.

One more conclusion can be drawn that : Mozilla 3D developer view, does not deal with z index. It simply display the nested 3D view. Parent div will always be shown behind the child div in mozilla 3D view irrespective of its   z index. Kindly correct me if i am wrong somewhere.